# Eclipse is not setting "Import" statement automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I am hardcore Noobie in Java (and Eclipse) and this is my 1st Java code.

I am using VMware Java SDK and I am able to run the Java samples that come with the SDK. In one of the sample codes, I find this line:

```
import com.vmware.vcloud.sdk.Organization;
```

And the line in which this class is used is:

```
for (ReferenceType vdcLink : Organization 
                .getOrganizationByReference(vcloudClient, orgRef)
                .getVdcRefs())
```

Here I understand how `Organization` is imported and being used.

Now, I am writing my own code in Eclipse and not able to make "Organization" work. Eclipse is not writing the `import` (however, Eclipse is auto-writing the `import` statements for few other methods that I used from the same SDK)

Here is what I did:

I did make sure that I import all the .jar files (that come from the VMware SDK) into Eclipse at `Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries`.

I am also running `CTRL+Shift+O` to arrange the imports.

I have also set `Windows > Preferences > "Save Actions"` and checked `"Organize Imports"` so that it will arrange the imports every time I save the program.

However, I am just not able to get `Organization` work.

So from the sample code (which is working), I copied the below line to my code:

```
import com.vmware.vcloud.sdk.Organization;
```

But still it is not working. Needless to say, If I type `Organization.` and then do a `CTRL + Space` (to show autocomplete suggestions), it does not show any methods in the pop up.

I am thinking this is somehow related to the setting of the .jar file paths but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
This is the error I get when I use "Organization": This error pops up in a box when I move my mouse cursor to the Red dot on the far left of the line where I wrote `Organization`:

```
Multiple Markers At this line
    -Orgnization cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: Does eclipse highlight this import with red?

Comment: Does autocomplition work for JDK classes? For example `java.util.Collection`.

Comment: No. If I manually copy the `import com.vmware.vcloud.sdk.Organization`, it does not show anthing in red. but then I get red when I use `Orgnization`

Comment: And what is in Errors view?

Comment: @AlexR don't know what you mean by collection. Must be something in Java that I don't know..

Comment: The class *could* be package protected. Check that the sample class you lifted the code from isn't in the same package as the class you are trying to use.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer I mean `Window` -> `Show View` -> `Markers`

Comment: I would guess that the usage does not point to a class but variable. Try before typing in `new Organization(` or check the syntax, colon instead of semicolon on the line before.

Comment: `Orgnization` is it a mistype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

I got it working as below. Not sure whether it makes any sense to you guys. But an explanation would be really helpful:

My sample code has below things:

In Eclipse, it is located in `project->src->com->vmware->vcloud->sdk->samples` folder
And it has this line at the top: `package com.vmware.vcloud.sdk.samples;`

So I move my code from `project->src` to `project->src->com->vmware->vcloud->sdk->samples` and added that package line to my code.

Now eclipse is writing the import statement for `Organization` as well as eclipse shows me available methods for `Organization.`

Now,

I don’t want to write my code inside the samples folder. 
Is this even making any sense??

Thanks for the comments. I got this idea after reading your comments.